# A mechanic's problem using dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

This should be an easy exercise but I am stuck somehow in the definition of the equilibrium point:

> Consider that the energy $V(u)$ on every point of a cement pile $u$ away from the stable state, satisfy the equation:
>   $$\frac{dV}{du}=kL^2\sin(2u)-2PL\sin(u),$$
>   where $k,L,P$ are positive constants. Find all equilibrium points, namely the values of $V$ that correspond to distances $u$, where $V$ is constant.

But if we consider the function $f(u)=kL^2\sin(2u)-2PL\sin(u)$, I do not see how it is possible $f(u)=0$, for every $u\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Later mark. I post also a figure just in case this makes the situation more clear...[image]

Comment: Why would $f(u) = 0$ for all $|u| < {\pi \over 2}$?

Comment: @dmtri: For example, we could have critical points as $$u = n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @copper.hat , That is also my question.

Comment: Are you sure it is not saying **for some** $u$ instead of **for every** $u$?

Comment: @Moo, critical yes, but the definition of a equilibrium point demands for every $u$. That is,  $V$ is equilibrium if $f(u,V)=0$ for every $u\in(-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$.

Comment: Can you please post exactly what is written, because something is wrong here?

Comment: I added something more, trying to translate it to English. @Moo

Comment: It makes no sense to me. $V$ is not constant. I presume the question is badly worded and what is desired is the $u$ for which $V'(u) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find critical points, you need values of $u$ such that $V'(u) = 0$
$$V'=a\sin 2u -b\sin u = 0$$
Therefore,
$$2a\sin u \cos u - b\sin u = 0$$
So, either
$$\sin u = 0$$
or 
$$\cos u = \frac{b}{2a}=\frac{P}{kL}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: For critical points, your assertion is ok, but I need to find the equilibrium points...

Comment: @dmtri : Your differential equation, the mechanical system, is quite probably $$m\ddot u=-\frac{d}{du}V(u)$$ so that the equilibrium points really are the maxima and minima of $V$, that is the roots of $V'$.

Comment: Your problem is a physical understanding not a mathematical one. An equilibrium point is merely a point $u^*$ for which $V’(u^*)=0$. In other words if you placed the system at that point, there would be no action.  Consider another system that represents a parabolic energy well $V’=u$. Th equilibrium point is $u^*=0$.

Comment: @LutzL,  thanks for the feedback but still I cannot understand the $\frac{d^2u}{d? ^2} $ you mention in your equation.  Is not here $u$ the independent variable?

Comment: That comment was from before you posted the image. Now I'm at a loss what $V$ exactly represents. Is the beam vibrating or stationary? Are the springs mounted to a point or is there some more distributed interaction?

Comment: @LutzL, just a recommendation, put @...the person you want to address your post,  otherwise he will never get the notification,  unless it is under his question and not on others answers.